# Android Draw line Animation on Image Border only

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, draw

i have one image view. i set one image from  drawable to that image view. now i want to draw line on the border of that image. can anyone help to achieve this? i examined using path its can be done. i want to draw line only on the border of that image in animated way... Thanks in advance..

i'm trying like this

```
     Path path = new Path();
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    path.addRect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(),view.getRight(),view.getBottom(),Path.Direction.CW);
     Paint p = new Paint();
     p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     c.drawPath(path, p);
```

Answer (score -1):

simple solution to that would be to create a shape in the drawable folder with the stroke of which ever color and width you want and then just put it as the image background this will appear as the border for the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
    <stroke 
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="#ffffff"
        />
</shape>
```

now just set this drawble as the image background in the layout file and you will see the white border around the image

Comment: I don't want to set border ..I want to draw line in animation on border of that image view.

Answer (score -2):

It produces precisely an animated line and you can just adjust the path to the edge of your view to create a border. For example:

Define a path by your view parameters / arbitrary shape:

```
Path path = new Path();
Canvas c = new Canvas();
 Paint mPaint= new Paint();
path.addRect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom(), Path.Direction.CW);
PathEffect pe = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10, 5, 5, 5}, phase);
mPaint.setPathEffect(pe);
c.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

or you can with xml  as like that

drawable/dotted.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />
</shape>
```

view.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />
```

Comment: i tried with that same code above but nothing comes in my screen . i have same image only.

Comment: Path path = new Path();
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
  Paint mPaint= new Paint();
  //player is my image here
  path.addRect(player.getLeft(), player.getTop(), player.getRight(), player.getBottom(), Path.Direction.CW);
  PathEffect pe = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10, 5, 5, 5}, phase);
  mPaint.setPathEffect(pe);
  mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  c.drawPath(path, mPaint);